# How to overflow one section of a modal window using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I've created a modal window with 2 sections: a `header` and a `ul`. I use jQuery to open the modal. So far so good. I want to make the `ul` fit the modal box without overflowing.

I can overflow the `.modal`. But, i really just to want to overflow the `ul`, not the entire `.modal` box.

https://jsfiddle.net/tjL1e0ca/

```js
$(document).on("click", "h3", function(e) {
  $(".modal").css("display", "block");
})
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 30px 20px 20px;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.modal_1 ul {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>click here to open modal</h3>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal_1">
    <div>
      <h1>HEADER GOES HERE</h1>
      <h2>SUB GOES HERE</h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: You can use the `< >` editor button to insert executable HTML-CSS-JS snippets directly within SO. I've edited your question for you.

Comment: You might also want `$(this).find("+.modal").css("display", "block");` to show the next sibling of the clicked heading instead of all elements havings a specific class.

Answer (score 4):

Add `style="overflow-y: auto; height: 100px;"` to your `ul`. This basically adds `overflow-y` to your ul, except it would only work if you specify a height.

I updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35s21aep/) for you.

Change the height as you wish.

**Update:** After reading the coments, I realized that you wanted the height of the ul to be adaptive and not set. To fix that, change the height from `height: 100px;` to `height: 50%;` (and change the percentage as you wish). That way, the ul will always be 50% of the modal, no matter the height of the modal. Since it didn't seem to work on snippets here, I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/notu5pa4/) for you.

```js
$(document).on("click", "h3", function(e) {
  $(".modal").css("display", "block");
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 700;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 30px 20px 20px;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.modal_1 ul {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>click here to open modal</h3>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal_1">
    <div>
      <h1>HEADER GOES HERE</h1>
      <h2>SUB GOES HERE</h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: absolutely correct; I'd advise using classes over inline style tho

Comment: FYI: You can use the `< >` editor button to insert executable HTML-CSS-JS snippets directly within SO. I've edited your answer for you.

Comment: @JohnVandivier Most of the time, I do use classes. I just became a bit lazy this time. I'll change my code above.

Comment: @AniketG This solution almost works, The height is already defined by the `.modal` class. The `.list` needs to take the remaining space

Comment: @Marco I changed my solution up a bit. Please let me know if that's the solution you wanted. I didn't update the snippet since it wouldn't work correctly. View the JSFiddle